# Regex - Select the entire file that contains an word in textcrawler

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

I need to select and delete all content of those files that contains word "MY_WORD".

```
blah blagh
tata MY_WORD ppp
mother id 787
```

I try this regex `(?s)(.*?MY_WORD).*$` or  `[^"]+(MY_WORD)[^"]+`  and works in notepad++, but doesn't work in **TextCrawler**.

Comment: It think it is the `(?s)` for specifying a single line regex that TextCrawler doesn't like. Isn't there any other way in this editor to choose regex options?

Comment: what your textcrawler version? I test with v3.0 it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try this approach:

```
.*MY_WORD.*
```

and also need to **check** "Dot matches newline".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`(?s).*\b(MY_WORD)\b.*`

or

`[^*]+(MY_WORD)[^*]+`